# Can I use the right hand rule in a three-dimensional subspace?

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, orientation

I have a seemingly innocent (possibly trivial) question about the notion of orientation on vector spaces.

Given a three-dimensional subspace $\Sigma$ of $\mathbb{R}^{d \geq 4}$ (the latter equipped with its standard orientation), let $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ be two orthogonal vectors in $\Sigma$.

**Question.** Can I use the "right hand rule" to define a "positively oriented" basis of $\Sigma$? In other words, if for some reason $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ have a natural order, is there any obstruction in defining (canonically) a positively oriented basis of $\Sigma$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*I may misunderstand the problem...*

Anyway, from what I read, $\Sigma$ is a 3D space, so you can equip it with a canonical basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$, which provides an orientation of $\Sigma$, and then work in $\Sigma$ as you would do in the usual 3D oriented space, using the right-hand rule.

In other words, from what you described, I don't see what the role of $\mathbb R^{\ge 4}$ is.

Comment: Thanks for the help! How can I equip $\Sigma$ with a *canonical* basis? If $(e_{1}, \dotsc, e_{d})$ is the standard basis of $\mathbb{R}^{d}$, then I can map $v_{1}$ to $e_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ to $e_{2}$; yet I need to pick a vector in the orthogonal complement of $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ in $\Sigma$ to define a isomorphism $\Sigma \to \mathbb{R}^{3} \subset \mathbb{R}^{d}$.

Comment: As the dimension of $\Sigma$ is equal to three, a canonical basis is just any orthonormal vectors $\{e_1,e_2,e_3\}$ of $\Sigma$. Complement this into an orthonormal basis $\{e_1,e_2,e_3, e_4, \dots, e_d\}$ of $V= \mathbb R^{\ge 4}$. For any vector $x \in \Sigma$, $x_i = 0$ for $i \ge 4$. Hence, for any $v_1, v_2 \in \Sigma$ orthogonal, ignore the vanishing coordinates, compute $v_1 \wedge v_2$ based on the first three coordinates (that is the right-hand rule) and add zero to the other coordinates to go back in $\mathbb R^{\ge 4}$.

Comment: Sorry I am confused, If $(v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3})$ is an orthogonal basis of $\Sigma$, then the same holds for $(v_{1}, v_{2}, -v_{3})$. How do I know which is the "right" basis? My $\Sigma$ is not necessarily spanned by $e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3}$.

Comment: OK I see it now, I can certainly map $(v_{1}, v_{2}, v_{3})$ to $(e_{1}, e_{2}, e_{3})$. So the right choice of $v_{3}$ is the one corresponding to a map of positive determinant.

Comment: @MK7 That is correct.

Comment: By the way, where is the problem coming from? Something you want to solve or for the *pure beauty*!